# How to pass condition statement as argument to functions in zsh?

Tags: bash, shell-script, zsh

I have defined a function similar to the following (as an alias),

```bsh
testif() {
    ([ $1 ]) && echo "true" || echo "false"
}
```

..and then was able to call `testit "1 == 2"` in **bash** shell and the output was `false` as expected. But it is not working in **zsh**. The output to the same call in zsh is `true`.

1. Is it possible to code such a function for zsh?
2. Why it is giving wrong output in zsh? shouldn't zsh bash compatible?

Comment: 1. zsh is not bash-compatible. 2. it will (scarequotes) "work" in zsh if you change the `$1` to `$=1`. 3. don't ever use `a && b || c` -- it's not similar to `a ? b : c` or `if a; then b; else c; fi`.

Comment: Time to change all my scripts then..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did doesn't work in bash either except in very simple examples.

```
$ testif 'hello world = hello world'
bash: [: too many arguments
false
$ testif '"hello world" = "hello world"'
bash: [: too many arguments
false
$ testif '* = *'
(usually false with an error message, but it depends on the files in the current directory)
```

Even your simple example doesn't work in zsh because unlike other sh-like shells, in zsh, `$1` really means “take the value of the first argument” (almost: if the expansion results in an empty word, it's removed altogether). In bash and other sh-like shells, `$1` means “take the value of the first argument, split it into words and treat each word as a glob pattern” which is almost never what you want.

---

You can pass a condition in the syntax of the `test`/single-brackets command as **separate** arguments.

```bash
testif () {
  if [ "$@" ]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
}
```

This works (with the limitations of the `[` command, e.g. no `&&` and `||` operators.

```
$ testif '*' = '*'
true
$ testif hello = hello
true
$ testif 'hello world' = 'hello world'
true
$ testif 0 = 00
false
$ testif 0 -eq 00
true
```

There's rarely a good reason to pass a `[` condition around, though. You might as well pass the whole command. This not only lets you pass other kinds of conditions (e.g. `grep …` or `if systemctl is-active …`), but if you need more than a simple command, you can define an auxiliary function.

```bash
testif () {
  if "$@"; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi
}
```

```
$ testif [ 'hello world' = 'hello world' ]
true
$ testif grep -q : /etc/passwd
true
```

Another approach would be to pass the whole command as a single string, and use `eval` inside the function.

```bash
testif () {
  if eval "$1"; then echo true; else echo false; fi
}
```

```
$ testif '[ "hello world" = "hello world" ]'
true
$ testif '[ "hello world" = "h*" ]'
false
$ testif '[[ "hello world" = "h*" ]]'
false
$ testif '[[ "hello world" = h* ]]'
true
```